# How to color arrows using the epslatex terminal and 'with vectors'

Tags: gnuplot

I know from [Gnuplot coloring 3D-vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503786/gnuplot-coloring-3d-vectors) how one is supposed to color arrows. However, under Windows Gnuplot 4.6 Patchlevel 5 the following MWE does not produce red arrows but simply black ones.

```
reset
set terminal epslatex size 15cm,9.27cm color colortext 8 dashed

set style arrow 1 linecolor rgb "red"

file = 'OutputSetting0'
set output 'Setting0/test.tex'

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set zrange [-1:1]

set arrow 1 from -1,0,0 to 1,0,0 arrowstyle 1

splot file u (0):(0):(0):2:3:4 with vectors arrowstyle 1

reset
exit
```

The extra arrow added by hand (`set arrow ...`) is colored red. However, the one with position data read from file is still black.

Is there another way how one could achieve colored arrows from file (except changing the terminal which is out of the question)?

As requested here is also a MWE of LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}           

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \input{Setting0/test}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Linux. The only issue is that I have to add `\usepackage{color}` to the preamble in the parent latex file before I can `\input{test}`. Maybe you can show a MWE of your latex file as well?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems to be a bug?
Adding `set hidden3d` made my arrows go red. I promise I didn't touch any other part of my script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a bug. Please make sure that you don't have any old files around (also no automatically converted `pdf` file of the image).

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage{epstopdf}` is triggering it? Does the eps file generated by gnuplot directly (i.e. before you run `latex`) look OK?

Comment: The actual eps file does not look OK (black arrow, too). I tried it in a clean (empty folder) Environment.